# Package Class Library for multiple targets including .NET Core

Tags: .net, nuget, coreclr

I have a simple class library that targets `.NET 4.5` and is packaged as a `nuget package`. It depends on `Reactive Extensions (2.2.5)`.

I'd like to make it `.NET` core compatible and package it for multiple target frameworks `(.NET Core, .NET 4.5, .NET 4.6)`.

I've upgraded my Reactive Extensions `nuget` dependency to `3.0.0`, and using API Port I've learned that my code is now 100% `.NET Core` compatible.

Now I'm working on building and packaging my class library so that it can be consumed by multiple framework targets.
 What's the proper way to do that?
 Is there published guidance on this?

Do I need to create a new .NET Core Class Library in VS2015 or can I do this in place on my old .NET Framework Class Library?

Do I add a project.json and add multiple frameworks, like this?

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "net45": {}, 
    "net46":  {}
  }
```

Do I still use nuget for packaging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use netstandard to easily target mulitple frameworks. Guidance on netstandard is available [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md). To do this you would need to have a NET Core project. This is future proof and much easier to manage than using PCL profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I created a nuget package with a netstandard1.6 target. It is consumable by both net461 apps and netcoreapp1.0 apps.

I found that the netstandard1.6 target is not consumable by net45, so I added a separate net45 target too.

Here's the project.json.

`{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "System.Reactive": "3.0.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        },
        "net45": {}
    },
    "buildOptions": {
        "xmlDoc": true
    }
}`